# O que faz o método addViewControllers da classe WebMvcConfigurer do Spring boot?

Tags: java, mvc, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Estou  usando thymeleaf no front end da aplicação e tenho a seguinte classe de configuração, com o metodo addViewControllers em questão :

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    ...

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/admin/home").setViewName("adminhome");
        registry.addViewController("/user/perfil/{email}").setViewName("userperfil");
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        //registry.addViewController("/403").setViewName("403");  
       } 
         ...
    }
```

Estava pensando que ele seria responsável por modificar as urls mostradas na barra do browser, porem,não fez isso. Então não sei o que ele faz..

Testei com essa url existente em um dos controllers da aplicação por exemplo:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("user")
public class UserController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

...

    //metodo bastante simplificado..
    @RequestMapping(value = "/perfil/{email}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView perfil(@PathVariable("email") String email) {

        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView();

            User user = userService.findByEmail(email);

                view.addObject("user", user);

                view.setViewName("usuario/perfil");
                LOG.info("Metodo perfil");
                return view;

    }

    ...
}
```

Assim no método addViewControllers coloquei:

```
registry.addViewController("/user/perfil/{email}").setViewName("userperfil");
```

imaginando que no browser ficaria assim:

```
http://localhost:8080/userperfil
```

ao invés de :

```
http://localhost:8080/user/perfil/kiko@gmail.com
```

Alem do que seria possível definir essas urls "editadas"?

Answer (score 0):

addViewController é responsável por mapear o caminho enquanto setViewName é responsável pelo mapeamento do jsp a ser carregado.

é possível também usar esse método pra redirecionamentos,exemplo:

```
registry.addRedirectViewController("/home", "/user/perfil/{email}");
```

no exemplo acima ao tentar acessar http://localhost:8080/home ele redirecionaria para http://localhost:8080/user/perfil/kiko@gmail.com

mais informações:

[Exemplo spring 4 mvc por Arvind Rai](https://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-mvc-without-controller-using-viewcontrollerregistry-with-addviewcontroller-addredirectviewcontroller-and-addstatuscontroller-example)

Comment: Obrigado ai pela ajuda mas, é exatemente o contrario de seu exemplo, Legal esse método,Ele funciona mesmo eu tento os meus controllers já definidos? Nesse caso o UserCotroller?

Comment: Então, pelo que eu entendo ele é uma substituição, então acho que no seu caso não. Outra coisa, você disse que o exemplo está ao contrário, então ao acessar o user/perfil/email ele iria pra home? Não tenho como testar aqui pra ver e queria editar a resposta pra quem fosse ver.